# How to have changing x-axis intervals in one Graph using Date? (ggplot)

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, scaling

I am trying to plot a time series using ggplot. I have aggregated monthly and weekly data for the last couple of years. I want my plot to show monthly data for five years until a certain cut-off. After this cut-off I want to show weekly data for one year. However, I want those two parts to be off the same horizontal length so that the weekly data can be seen in more detail. Is there a way to scale the x axis manually so that half of it covers a five-year period and the other half of it covers the adjacent one-year period?

I have tried to find an answer for a long-period of time and would be very grateful if somebody had an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to tell without a reproducible example, but it sounds like your data are probably something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(dates = c(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), 
                               as.POSIXct("2018-12-01"), by = "1 month"),
                           seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"), by = "1 week",
                               length.out = 52)),
                 values = (cumsum(runif(112, -0.4, 0.6)) + 10) * 1000)

ggplot(df, aes(dates, values)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

If you want your plot split into two panels, the easiest way to achieve this is to create a new column that denotes which panel you want each row to be in;

```r
df$Period = as.factor(df$date > as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"))
levels(df$Period) <- c("Monthly (pre 2019)", "Weekly (2019")
```

Now you can just plot with `facet_grid` according to your new factor:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(dates, values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(.~Period, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The idea with facet is great and comes very close to what I had in mind. However my initial goal was to have it all in one coherent panel. Maybe you have a suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: @Max it is possible to do this just by removing the panel margins and facet strips. However, this is a somewhat misleading way to label an axis